# top and bottom layers or top and bottom layer?

Tags: grammar

> The tower will be constructed using stone and brick as bottom and top
>   **layer(s)** respectively.

Let's suppose there are two layers. Which one is correct here, layer or layers?

According to [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=top%20and%20bottom%20layer%2C%20top%20and%20bottom%20layers&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctop%20and%20bottom%20layer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctop%20and%20bottom%20layers%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctop%20and%20bottom%20layer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctop%20and%20bottom%20layers%3B%2Cc0), out of these two options, "top and bottom layers" was more commonly used than "top and bottom layer". Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two layer**s**, so it should be *top and bottom layer**s***. Think of '[your left and right hand**s**](https://www.livescience.com/what-causes-left-handedness.html)', or '[up and down quark**s**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark)'.